# Why do templates never update dynamic variables after cached?

Tags: theming, 8, sessions

Given my twig extension:

```
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class RainbirdTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  public function getGlobals() {
       $session = new Session();
       return array(
           'session' => $session->all()
       );
   }


  public function getFilters()  {
      return array(
          'getservertimezone'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'getServerTimeZone'),
      );
  }

  public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('render_menu',
        array($this, 'render_menu'),
        array('is_safe' => array('html'))
      ),
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('session_var',
        array($this, 'session_var'),
        array('is_safe' => array('html'))
      )
    );
  }

  /**
   * Gets a unique identifier for this Twig extension.
   */
  public function getName() {
    return 'rainbird_twig_extension';
  }

  public function session_var($key) {
    $session = new Session();
    return $session->get($key);
  }

  public function getServerTimeZone()   {

       if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
           return date_default_timezone_get();
       } else if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
           return ini_get('date.timezone');
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }


  /**
     * Provides function to programmatically rendering a menu
     *
     * @param String $menu_name
     *   The machine configuration id of the menu to render
     */
    public function render_menu($menu_name) {
      $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();

      // Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
      $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

      // Load the tree based on this set of parameters.
      $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

      // Transform the tree using the manipulators you want.
      $manipulators = array(
        // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
        array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
        // Use the default sorting of menu links.
        array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
      );
      $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

      // Finally, build a renderable array from the transformed tree.
      $menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);

      return  array('#markup' => drupal_render($menu));
    }

}
```

or module hook:

```
function rainbird_theme_preprocess_block__personaselector(&$variables){
  $session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();
  $variables['mypersona'] = $session->get('mypersona');
  // kint($variables); die(); - THIS ONLY HAPPENS WITH CLEAR CACHE
}
```

and my module's services.yml

```
services:
  rainbird.rainbirdsubscriber:
    class: Drupal\rainbird\EventSubscriber\RainbirdSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
  rainbird.twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\rainbird\RainbirdTwigExtension
    public: false
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

and my sites/default/services.yml

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 100
    gc_maxlifetime: 200000
agents,
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
  renderer.config:
    required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']
    auto_placeholder_conditions:
      max-age: 0
      contexts: ['session', 'user']
      tags: []
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false
  factory.keyvalue:
    {}
  factory.keyvalue.expirable:
    {}
  filter_protocols:
    - http
    - https
    - ftp
    - news
    - nntp
    - tel
    - telnet
    - mailto
    - irc
    - ssh
    - sftp
    - webcal
    - rtsp
  cors.config:
    enabled: false
    allowedHeaders: []
    allowedMethods: []
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    exposedHeaders: false
    maxAge: false
    supportsCredentials: false
```

i've tried all of these in `block--myblock.html.twig`:

```
RESET1: {{ app.session.mypersona }}
RESET2: {{ session_var('mypersona') }}
RESET3: {{ app.session.get('mypersona') }}
RESET4: {{ mypersona }}
RESET5: {{ session.get('mypersona') }}
RESET6: {{ session.mypersona }}
RESET7: {{ session.get('mypersona') }}
RESET8: {{ dump(session) }}
RESET9: {{ dump(app) }}
```

yet NOTHING updates `myperson` after the template is cached by twig/symfony/drupal. ?

I've disabled: `devel`, `twig_tweak` and `settings.local.php`.

WTF am i doing wrong?

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put new data in a block you also need the cache metadata for this:

```
function rainbird_theme_preprocess_block__personaselector(&$variables){
  $session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();
  $variables['mypersona'] = $session->get('mypersona');
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';
}
```

Comment: i tried that and `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';` and `$variables['elements']['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';` but still no go. Additionally i can put `kint($variables); die(__FUNCTION__);` in the `rainbird_theme_preprocess_block__personaselector` but only get the variables dumped when the cache is cleared. So the whole hook is only called once.

Comment: If the cache data in the render array is correct, then you have a problem with the block twig. There are some bad examples around, that ignore the content of the block and use the block template to print own variables. Better use a custom template for this.

Comment: the block is custom. should i paste a devel dump of it's configuration? What do you mean by these examples. I've pasted the relevant part of my block template where it says RESET1-9 above. How else should i be accessing the variable?

Comment: Try this block template http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/themes/stable/templates/block/block.html.twig. The content of the block is a normal render array with render elements or custom templates.

Comment: how would the generic template help me at all? Our site is able to render and updates fields / variables across pages, when set from nodes, views, etc... However own custom variables changes are ignored.

Comment: This is an example how a block template should look like. You can customize, but it should not look like the example in the question. Important is that you use the variable {{ content }}.

Comment: so then how do you reconstruct $content with my own template?

Comment: In a block plugin what build() returns does end up in {{ content }} of the template. In {{ content }} is a render array. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-from-custom-module. This example is a controller, but a block is the same.

Comment: nothing I did in the hook from your answer fixed my problem, but I got it working using my template above by returning renderable arrays in `mymodule_theme` and in the `build()` and `content()` functions of `class PersonaContext extends BlockBase`... Do you want to rewrite an answer I can accept for these next folks?

Comment: The preprocess hook is from your question, added one line how to use a context for the session to answer the question in the title. Theming of blocks is too broad for an answer. If you have a more specific question, open another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Twig cache from **services.yml** inside `docroot/sites/default` directory as

```
# Twig auto-reload:
#
# Automatically recompile Twig templates whenever the source code changes.
# If you don't provide a value for auto_reload, it will be determined
# based on the value of debug.
#
# Not recommended in production environments
# @default null
auto_reload: true
```

**Or,**

```
# Twig cache:
#
# By default, Twig templates will be compiled and stored in the filesystem
# to increase performance. Disabling the Twig cache will recompile the
# templates from source each time they are used. In most cases the
# auto_reload setting above should be enabled rather than disabling the
# Twig cache.
#
# Not recommended in production environments
# @default true
cache: false
```

**Note:** auto_reload setting above should be enabled rather than disabling the Twig cache.

Comment: This is only for the precompiled twig code. Does not change the render cache.

Comment: @AshishDeynap, thank you, however i've had both of those settings in place in the sites/default/services.yml throughout all my testing.